# CLang libc, libc++ on Windows with debugging symbols compatible with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, llvm, clang, libc

I'm trying to find info and I don't see it on clang web site.
I'm thinking to try to use it on windows, but I have no clue if it has it's own libc or it uses broken libc from MS?

another question: if i compile code with clang, will I be able to use visual studio as a debugger, e.g. is clang capable of emitting debugging symbols in MS format (this is the reason I don't want to use gcc; and this is something that intel compiler can do, but it uses MS's libc).

In short, I'd like to be able to use visual studio as a debugger, but I need at the same time decent real c compiler with normal lib c.

or, perhaps, there are commercial alternatives. I've read that dinkum sells commercial libc for Win32 and others, but I have no clue what's the price and how to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have asked two completely different questions.  I will answer the one about using Visual Studio as a debugger.

This is not currently possible.  Microsoft has not released any documentation or code necessary to produce files in their PDB format, which is what Visual Studio consumes.  There has been some reverse engineering efforts, but results of those have not yet made their way into general Open Source tools.

Neither GCC nor Clang are capable of producing PDB files, and hence do not work with Microsoft's debugger.  Some of the commercial compilers have support for generating or consuming PDB, but not the Free/Open compilers like GCC and Clang.

You can use other IDEs on Windows which support the DWARF debugging format, used by GCC and Clang.  Such compilers include Code::Blocks and Eclipse CDT.

Comment: That's what I pretty much knew about pdb's. Are any of these IDEs are comparable in usability to visual studio integrated debugger? So far, I wasn't even able to use anything. I need tools, not toys ;) I tried code blocks, it's nice, but didn't try it as a debugger. If it was comparable to visual studio debugger I'd probably use it at work.

Comment: Nothing is as good as the VS debugger if you like the graphical integration, in my experience, but I haven't tried either in a year or two.  Maye they've gotten better.  Can't hurt to test them out and see if they work for you.

Comment: I have same experience. Nothing comes even close. I haven't tried other tools in a while also, but it's hard to imagine that all linux devs don't have similarly productive tools (valgrind being biggest exception)

Comment: Linux devs still think Vim/Emacs are the pinnacle of code manipulation tools.  Some are still outright hostile to the idea that a good tool can do more than move text around or that it try to actually understand the meaning and structure of the program that text represents.  You should not be surprised at all.  (I was a diehard Linux/Vim user for many years, and used to fall into that category of people before learning the error of my ways.) there are some efforts around Clang finally to improve the situation, but a true VS killer is still many years away.

Comment: Your comments about PDB is not entirely correct. The approach would be to have Clang populate the objects with CV8 debuginfo data, and then use Microsoft's linker to link the binary and write the CV8 data to a PDB file.
There's no need to support PDB directly if MS's link.exe is used to link.
CodeView (CV8) is actually fairly well known, although microsoft have some minor tweaks to the format.
I know one project that has comprehensive CodeView debug output; that is DMD (the reference D compiler, which can output MSVC compatible objects). That code could potentially be used by Clang.

Comment: @TurkeyMan: fair enough. I was under the impression that the CV8 format was significantly limited in capabilities compared to Microsoft's current internal formats, especially as it comes to more recent C++ features.

Comment: I think their current format is just some extra bits added to the original CV8 data. I don't think there's a new format in the object files. The pdb is a bi-product, generated by the linker from the data in object files.
Walter (from DMD) reverse engineered some of the MS bits in the MS-COFF CV8 data and supports it in DMD. That's the best resource I know at this time.

Comment: I suggest editing your original reply, it's not entirely factual. It's not the job of the compiler to produce the PDB as you suggest, that's the linker, and it's fine to use the MS linker which can produce the PDB with the other compilers *if* they write compatible object files. Clang produces compatible objects, and is making an effort to support the debuginfo too. GCC is also capable of producing compatible COFF object files, but it's not capable of populating them with debuginfo, and I don't think that's on the map.

Comment: Feel free to edit it or down vote or post a new answer. I'm not by a real computer and I will certainly forget about your suggestion by the time I am. :)