# Visual Studio can't find variables in symbols when used clang

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, debug-symbols

I have set Visual Studio 2013 to use clang from http://llvm.org/builds/
I can successfully compile C++ programs and create symbols by using /Zi compiler option. Once I start debugging the code I can use breakpoints (i.e. breakpoints work) but I can see no variables while Debugging. What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't know you could get VS to use Clang. Mind blown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048312/clang-libc-libc-on-windows-with-debugging-symbols-compatible-with-visual-stud might be your answer.

Comment: @Yakk: The question and the answer are more than 2 years old, and I know clang-cl.exe (the Visual Studio version of clang) can produce symbol files, e.g: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?54770-Using-Clang-to-compile-on-Windows